# How to run openshift online in Command promt Mac

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-online, openshift-web-console

I have a free trail account of openshift online. I have created an node application and a jenkins pipeline, now I want to add this to github webhooks, so I want to create a webhook. Usually when I use minishift I use oc describe bc/mynode. but how do I connect command prompt to openshift online

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer and ebook graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the web console, select the (?) menu top right and then select 'Command Line Tools'. It gives you the command in there to login. You can then use 'oc' commands.

If new to OpenShift, also read the free eBook:

- https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

which explains such details.